# Events and shared classes in multiple servers

Tags: c#, events, architecture

I plan to use events in a game server project, and I'm wondering what's the best design to use. Since I can't find any good examples for my problem, I'm asking here.

The server project structure I'm used to is pretty much this: I have a login server, a world/channel server, and a shared lib, for things like server and client classes, which are used by both. All communication code is here for example. The servers derive from a server class. The client class is a wrapper around a socket. Incoming data is parsed, and passed to packet handler methods.

Now I want to add an event, say, if a client connects all clients get notified. Instead of iterating over all connected clients, like I used to, the clients that connect have to subscribe to an event handler, which is fired from the connecting clients.

We're finally getting to my problem with my standard design, where do I put the callback? Normally I'd have to create a new method, like OnClientConnects or something, in the client class, to use for the event. But my servers are using the same client class, and putting event handlers for both of them in there seems dirty. I can't put it elsewhere, because the method needs information from the subcscriped client, like the socket.

The only other solution that comes to my mind are seperate client classes, or rather derived classes from it, for the different servers. Although this is a little tricky, with all the networking code inside the shared classes, because I have to get the custom client class in there, but it should be possible somewhow with overridden methods. And I guess that's all I can do.

All this feels kinda wrong though, and I'm wondering if this is really an acceptable design, or if there's a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to get a clear picture without a white board a bunch of questions, but if it's any help...

Normally I would have a networking library that is shared between client and server. And some sort of `Application` or `Framework` class, that may contain things common to both client and server, including configuration reading, initialization of various subsystems (logging, threading, etc.).

Then, yes, I *would* have a derivation for client and the various server types (probably with an intermediate class for the various servers, as there is often functionality that is common to servers but separate from clients).

And to get to your specific question, I think it's fine to have that callback available to both clients and servers. It is quite reasonable for a server to want to do something when a client connects. Even if you have no need for it now, I can imagine you would in the future. At the very least, the server could log the event to the log file. But the point is that the handling of the callback belongs in the client/genericServer/loginServer/worldServer derived application classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The connect event was only an example though. Sure, that's one that probably both can use at some point, but there will definitly be unique events (probably a lot), that only one of the servers is using.

Comment: Fair enough. I was thinking that *those* callbacks would only need to go in the that particular derived server class.

Comment: Another approach might be to go with a more message-oriented approach. When an event of note happens, instantiate a message object, and send that message to relevant parties via TCP with a message type (`int` if you're payload conscious) in the header, then have the receiver run that through a message factory, creating an "implementation" version local only to the receiver, and this is the entry point to your custom code. This is the approach I've used on large-scale commercial projects. It offends some as "over-complicated", but you have complete control (including over performance).

Comment: Again, sorry if this isn't helpful. It's a broad question depending on a lot of details. Normally I would spend many hours having these types of discussions if I were collaborating on a project like this. Good luck to you!